# How do I turn off "Retrain OK, Google" notification?

Tags: notifications, google-assistant

Almost each time I look at the phone or unlock it, I get this notification:

[image: IMG:]

And it is really annoying. My phone is Huawei Mate 10 Pro, if that matters. Also, I checked into Settings, and Google Assistant is disabled. However, I am still getting these notifications.

How do I disable notification in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

- On your phone, touch and hold the Home button.
- On the top right, tap More and then Settings.
- Next to "Google Assistant," turn off the switch.

Comment: I don't have "more settings" option when holding home button...

Comment: It should open google assistant if you press and hold Home button. Or you can just open the google app